# How to efficiently delete elements from a vector given an another vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector

What is the best way to delete elements from a vector given an another vector?

I have come up with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

void remove_elements(vector<int>& vDestination, const vector<int>& vSource) 
{
    if(!vDestination.empty() && !vSource.empty())
    {
        for(auto i: vSource) {
            vDestination.erase(std::remove(vDestination.begin(), vDestination.end(), i), vDestination.end());
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    vector<int> v1={1,2,3};
    vector<int> v2={4,5,6};
    vector<int> v3={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    remove_elements(v3,v1);
    remove_elements(v3,v2);
    for(auto i:v3)
        cout << i << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here the output will be:

```
7
8
9
```

Comment: assuming that vectors will be large enough to justify even bothering with the optimizations, I would first transform `vDestination` to a `std::list` (or list of smart pointers?) to avoid costly removal from vector (because it has to be continuous) and back to `std::vector` at the end

Comment: @slawekwin: I strongly doubt that this will be faster for any realistic size of the vector. Lists require additional redirections and cannot be cached efficiently. (I am aware that element removal is O(1) for lists and O(N) for vectors.)

Comment: @Frank I am not sure about it as well, but I believe it would be an interesting experiment to measure it :)

Comment: Are all the vectors sorted?

Comment: might be worth checking out if creating an `unordered_set` (from `vSource`) first helps with efficiency. Theoretically should change worst case from `N * M` to `N + M` (assuming `N` is `vDestination` size and `M` is `vSource` size - one lookup per `vDestination` element instead of up to `M` lookups + set creation), but it depends on bucket configuration. Plus, you didn't mention what happens with duplicates - shall be removed once, or all of them?

Comment: @Bob__: No the vectors are not sorted, however in example they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that by *best* you mean *fastest that works*. Since it's a question about efficiency, I performed a simple benchmark to compare efficiency of several algorithms. Note that they differ a little, since the problem is a bit underspecified - the questions that arise (and assumptions taken for benchmark) are:

- is it guaranteed that `vDestination` contains all elements from `vSource` ? (assumption: no)
- are duplicates allowed in either `vDestination` or `vSource` ? (assumption: yes, in both)
- does the order of the elements in the result vector matter? (algorithms for both cases tested)
- should every element from `vDestination` be removed if it is equal to any element from `vSource`, or only one-for-one? (assumption: yes, in both)
- are sizes of `vDestination` and `vSource` somehow bounded? Is one of them always bigger or *much* bigger? (several cases tested)
- in the comments it's already explained that vectors don't need to be sorted, but I've included this point, as it's not immediately visible from the question (no sorting assumed in either of vectors)

as you see, there are a few points in which algorithms will differ and consequently, as you can guess, best algorithm will depend on your use case. Compared algorithms include:

1. original one (proposed in question) - baseline
2. proposed in @dkg answer
3. proposed in @Revolver_Ocelot answer + additional sorting (required by the algorithm) and pre-reservation of space for result
   vector
4. proposed  in @Jarod42 answer
5. set-based algorithm (presented below - mostly optimization of @Jarod42 algorithm)
6. counting algorithm (presended below)

set-based algorithm:

```
std::unordered_set<int> elems(vSource.begin(), vSource.end());
auto i = destination.begin();
auto target = destination.end();
while(i <= target) {
    if(elems.count(*i) > 0) 
        std::swap(*i, *(--target));
    else
        i++;
}
destination.erase(target, destination.end());
```

counting algorithm:

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> counts;     
counts.max_load_factor(0.3);     
counts.reserve(destination.size());      

for(auto v: destination) {     
    counts[v]++;     
}     

for(auto v: source) {     
    counts[v]--;     
}     

auto i = destination.begin();     
for(auto k: counts) {     
    if(k.second < 1) continue;            
    i = std::fill_n(i, k.second, k.first);     
}     
destination.resize(std::distance(destination.begin(), i));
```

Benchmarking procedure was executed using [Celero](https://github.com/DigitalInBlue/Celero/tree/v2.0.4) library and was the following:

1. Generate `n` pseudo-random `int`s (`n` in set `{10,100,1000,10000, 20000, 200000}`) and put them to a `vector`
2. Copy a fraction (`m`) of these ints to second `vector` (fractions from set `{0.01, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8}`, min. 1 element)
3. Start timer
4. Execute removal procedure
5. Stop timer

Only algorithms 3, 5 and 6 were executed on datasets larger than 10 000 elements as the rest of them took to long for me to comfortably measure (feel free to do it yourself).

Long story short: if your vectors contain less than 1000 elements, pick whichever you prefer. If they are longer - rely on size of `vSource`. If it's less than 50% of `vDestination` - choose set-based algorithm, if it's more - sort them and pick @Revolver_Ocelot's solution (they tie around 60%, with set-based being over 2x faster for `vSource` being 1% size of `vDestination`). Please don't rely on order or provide a vector that is sorted from the beginning - requirement that ordering has to remain same slows the process down dramatically. Benchmark on your use case, your compiler, your flags and your hardware. I've attached link to my benchmarks, in case you wanted to reproduce them.

Complete results (file `vector-benchmarks.csv`) are available on GitHub together with benchmarking code (file `tests/benchmarks/vectorRemoval.cpp`) [here](https://github.com/Lewerow/CppProjectTemplate/tree/vector-benchmark).

Please keep in mind that these are results that I've obtained on my computer, my compiler etc. - in your case they will differ (especially when it comes to point in which one algorithm is better than another).

I've used GCC 6.1.1 with `-O3` on Fedora 24, on top of VirtualBox.

Answer (score 6):

My version is the following, I only apply `erase` after all elements from the vector `vSource` have been moved to the end by `std::remove` and keep track of the pointer to the end of the vector `vDestination` to not iterate over it for nothing.

```
void remove_elements(vector<int>& vDestination, const vector<int>& vSource) 
{
    auto last = std::end(vDestination);
    std::for_each(std::begin(vSource), std::end(vSource), [&](const int & val) {
        last = std::remove(std::begin(vDestination), last, val);
    });
    vDestination.erase(last, std::end(vDestination));
}
```

See on coliru : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e86893babb6759c

---

**Update**

Here is a template version, so you don't care about the container type :

```
template <class ContainerA, class ContainerB>
void remove_elements(ContainerA & vDestination, const ContainerB & vSource) 
{
    auto last = std::end(vDestination);
    std::for_each(std::begin(vSource), std::end(vSource), [&](typename ContainerB::const_reference val) {
        last = std::remove(std::begin(vDestination), last, val);
    });
    vDestination.erase(last, std::end(vDestination));
}
```

---

**Note**

This version works for vectors without any constraints, if your vectors are sorted you can take some shortcuts and avoid iterating over and over the vector to delete each element.

Comment: Or with [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df3f23f7aa6f7f54) "STL-elegant" psychedelics.

Comment: @ilotXXI not sure if "remove_if" is necessary here. Considering "remove" does kind of the same for all elements with the same value.

Comment: @dkg: Thanks for the answer. How did you checked this is more efficient?

Comment: @Hayt, what do you mean? It iterates different values, not the same.

Comment: ah you are right. sorry I kind of missed you switched the inner/outer "loop". Would be interessting to see if there are performance changes. I have no access to a compiler at the moment though.

I can also see for "larger" vectors to put the source vector values into an unordered_set and just do a lookup if they are there to avoid repeated iteration over the source vector.

Answer (score 3):

If your vectors are always sorted, you can use `set_difference`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

void remove_elements(std::vector<int>& vDestination, const std::vector<int>& vSource) 
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    std::set_difference(vDestination.begin(), vDestination.end(), vSource.begin(), vSource.end(), std::back_inserter(result));
    vDestination.swap(result);
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v1={1,2,3};
    std::vector<int> v2={4,5,6};
    std::vector<int> v3={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    remove_elements(v3,v1);
    remove_elements(v3,v2);
    for(auto i:v3)
        std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

If not for reqirement, that output range should not ovelap with any input range, we could even avoid additional vector. Potentially you can roll your own version of `set_difference` which is allowed to output in range starting with `vDestination.begin()`, but it is outside of scope of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can be written with STL as:

```
void remove_elements(vector<int>& vDestination, const vector<int>& vSource) 
{
    const auto isInSource = [&](int e) {
        return std::find(vSource.begin(), vSource.end(), e) != vSource.end();
    };
    vDestination.erase(
        std::remove_if(vDestination.begin(), vDestination.end(), isInSource),
        vDestination.end());
}
```

if `vSource` is sorted, you may replace `std::find` by `std::binary_search`.

Comment: this solution is also in the first comment from the answer of @dkg

Comment: @Hayt: Indeed, I didn't follow the link.